# Run Time error 5

Tags: vba, excel

```
 Function GetUNC(strMappedDrive As String) As String
    Dim objFso As FileSystemObject
    Set objFso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim strDrive As String
    Dim strShare As String
    'Separated the mapped letter from
    'any following sub-folders
    strDrive = objFso.GetDriveName(strMappedDrive)
    'find the UNC share name from the mapped letter
    strShare = objFso.Drives(strDrive).ShareName '<<<< this is the line that the code fails on
    'The Replace function allows for sub-folders
    'of the mapped drive
    GetUNC = Replace(strMappedDrive, strDrive, strShare)
    Set objFso = Nothing 'Destroy the object
End Function
```

It works fine on my laptop and network, but when a colleague uses the same spreadsheet with the same code on their laptop and network the code throws a run-time error 5 exception 'invalid procedure call or argument' at the following line:

```
strShare = objFso.Drives(strDrive).ShareName
```

When I hover over the line of code I see:  when I run the code to this point I see a file path.

My colleague has tried running the code on his local drive as well as a network drive with no success.  We both have the same references selected as well. Does anyone know what I need to do to get this working on my colleagues machine?

Comment: What does `debug.print strMappedDrive` say?

Comment: Hi findwindows, strMappedDrive has a path: strMappedDrive = "\\dfz70680\folders\

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what the issue is, but it might be worth using an API call instead:

```
#If Win64 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function WNetGetConnection32 Lib "MPR.DLL" Alias "WNetGetConnectionA" (ByVal lpszLocalName As String, ByVal lpszRemoteName As String, lSize As Long) As Long
#Else
    Declare Function WNetGetConnection32 Lib "MPR.DLL" Alias "WNetGetConnectionA" (ByVal lpszLocalName As String, ByVal lpszRemoteName As String, lSize As Long) As Long
#End If

Dim lpszRemoteName  As String * lBUFFER_SIZE
Dim lSize           As Long

Const NO_ERROR      As Long = 0&
Const lBUFFER_SIZE  As Long = 255&

Function GetUNC(ByRef strDriveLetter As String) As String
    strDriveLetter = UCase$(strDriveLetter) & ":"
    GetUNC = IIf(WNetGetConnection32(strDriveLetter, lpszRemoteName, lBUFFER_SIZE) = NO_ERROR, lpszRemoteName, "Error")
End Function
```

Then simply use something like:

```
MsgBox GetUNC("S")
```

Comment: Thanks Macro Man, but I get an error around ' : Declare Function WNetGetConnection32 Lib "MPR.DLL" Alias "WNetGetConnectionA" (ByVal lpszLocalName As String, ByVal lpszRemoteName As String, lSize As Long) As Long (the line is in red) - any idea how to fix? Thanks

Comment: That `If` block **must** include the hashtags (`#`) and must be the first thing in your module, before any other code

Comment: Thanks, it is, but still have the same problem

Comment: Sometimes it's a simply copy/paste issue. Sounds stupid but if you manually re-type that line it will probably go away.

Comment: Retyped the line now getting a compile error: 'The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems.  Please review and update Declare statements and then mark them with the PtrSafe attribute. ' - any idea what to do?

Comment: Have you used the hashtags(`#`) before `If/Else/EndIf`? They indicate conditional compilation and prevent that error from happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111017/discussion-between-macro-man-and-stacey).